# Python's argparse choose one of several optional parameter

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a program which can be used in the following way:

```
program install -a arg -b arg
program list
program update
```

There can only ever be one of the positional arguments specified (`install`, `list` or `update`). And there can only be other arguments in the `install` scenario.

The argparse documentation is a little dense and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this correctly. What should my `add_argument`s look like?

Comment: Did you look through the [argparse tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html) instead?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, no I didn't thanks for the link. I'll see what I can get from it.

Comment: @TankyWoo, read the last paragraph of my question. Also, having this information on SO makes it easier for other people looking for the same information. If RTFM was a blanket rule, SO wouldn't exist.

Comment: I agree with MaxMackie here. The `argparse` documentation is something I struggle with nearly every time I go to do something non-trivial with it.

Comment: @MaxMackie yes, the manual is very dense, but the `argparse` doc is very good, and if you want to master the commandline in python. I think you need to read it. Recently I write some nagios plugins in python, and the argparse is very important. So I have read the doc some times, it was really very good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like you want to use [`subparser`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

install = subparsers.add_parser('install')
install.add_argument('-b')
install.add_argument('-a')
install.set_defaults(subparser='install')

lst = subparsers.add_parser('list')
lst.set_defaults(subparser='list')

update = subparsers.add_parser('update')
update.set_defaults(subparser='update')

print parser.parse_args()
```

As stated in the docs, I have combined with [`set_defaults`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) so that you can know which subparser was invoked.

Comment: This looks nice and easy. I'll give it a try before accepting.

Comment: Works just like I need it to, however, in this situation, I have no way or knowing if `list` or `update` has been called seeing as they both return an empty dictionary. If there a built in way for me to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @MaxMackie -- That's there the `set_default` comes in.

Comment: Saw that, thanks for the example. `argparse` is so clean when you know how to use it :)

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty nice.  I'm a big fan.

Comment: @n0pe [and mgilson] use subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="cmd") instead of set_default.